# How do I clone git.ignore?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, clone

If I make the git.ignore in my local file then the some of public file in gihub will disappear.

And if I do git clone (my url) then the file from git.ignore will not be cloned.

How can I clone it?
(I am starting git and aws. I am tring to clone git file to aws server)

Comment: If you want the repo to track the file, why do you add it to .gitignore?

Comment: Note that `git.ignore` does not mean anything to Git; the file name `.gitignore`, which has the dot at the *front* of the name, not in the middle, does mean something to Git. This kind of pickiness matters because computers do what you tell them to, not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make `git` ignore certain files. See the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Out of the three ways described there only one puts the information about what files to ignore in the versioned content, so you get the information back out when cloning the repo. This is the usage of `.gitignore`-files.

So make sure you have file called `.gitignore` (preferably in the top level folder of your repo) and make sure it is checked in like a normal source file. That way when you clone the repo you also get the `.gitignore` file and `git` automagically knows what files to ignore even on the clone.